# why objects arent getting destroyed (raycast)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some 2D objets  ,I want them to dissapear when the mouse is over, the function OnMouseOver() dont work quite well,so I tried getting the mouse position, then check with the raycast if the 2D objects are colliding with the raycast,but I dont know why this is not working well,sometimes the object dont react ,sometimes multiple objects are deleted

```
  Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
  Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
  RaycastHit2D  hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.name == "item")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because when you say Destroy(gameObject); you are referring to your current GameObject(the that the script is attached to). Also instead of using hit.collider.name == "item", you should use a tag if(hit.collider.Comparetag("tagname")

Comment: I think the problem is not in that ,I  have already been trying to change the name to tag but it didnt worked ,I think the problem is that the condition is being respected in multiple objects ,because I didnt specificate where the mouse is  colliding  and multiple objects have the same name or tag ,now what Im trying to do is  to get the position of the hit.collider and compare it with the mouse position and get what is the closest object to the mouse  with the tag ("item")

Comment: Glad you accepted my answer! I hope your game is doing well and you keep up with coding.
Kind regards, SB

Answer (score 0):

oh,understood ! thank you SBfam 22 ,here is the changed code :

```
 Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
  Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
  RaycastHit2D  hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.name == "item")
        {
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
```